# Update таблицы по двум id

Tags: sql

Есть таблица студентов (id,name) предметов (id,title) и оценок(idStudent,idSubject, mark).
Каким  запросом мне изменить оценку по предмету по id студента и id предмета?

Comment: Запросом UPDATE. С соответствующим WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 update marks set mark = 3 where idStudent = 2 and idSubject = 1;
```